# How can I make gx recognise full URLs in vim?

Tags: external-command, netrw

By default, if a buffer in vim contains a URL such as `http://www.google.com`, <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> in normal mode will open a browser with that URL. That's very handy. However, if the URL has URL parameters (e.g. `http://www.google.com/search?q=stuff`), then the URL parameters are missed out (i.e. just `http://www.google.com/search` is opened).

I am using MacVim 7.4 patch 183, with Chrome as the primary browser (on OS X 10.9).

Is there an easy way, ideally with minimal customization, to make <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> recognise a full URL?

Comment: I can't reproduce that with vim 7.4 on linux. The parameter is passed to firefox correctly when using 'let g:netrw_browsex_viewer='firefox' for me.

Comment: @PhilippFrank The example URL doesn't work for me either (Vim 7.4, Linux) ... In any case, my solution is to select the URL in visual mode, and then use `gx` (which is not ideal but better than copy/paste).

Comment: @PhillippFrank, OK. I added my browser details. I don't set that variable explicitly.

Comment: Strange, I just tried this with `vim -u NONE`, and now it won't open at all; obviously I have a plugin doing something strange.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier The `gx` command is part of netrw, which is a plugin shipped with Vim. It's not loaded if `compatible` is set... Reading the help, I think you can use `g:netrw_gx` to configure/fix this btw...

Comment: @Andrew Ferrier: I needed to set that variable explicitly, otherwise gx would not work at all. I don't have access to chrome, but I tried konqueror and it's ok then. Maybe because you don't have that setting, netrw_filehandler is called and that borks it up.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker the strange thing is that I'm in `nocompatible` mode (starting vim the regular way), yet `set g:netrw_gx?` tells me it's an unknown option...

Comment: It's a variable, not an option, so you need to use `let`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with GVim 7.4 on Windows and Chrome. All the URLs you mentioned are opened exactly by `gx`.

Comment: Confirming the OP's error. Tried with VIM 7.4.473 & 7.4.663. Tried **from prestine user account** (without `.vimrc`), with different terminals (`urxvt`, `sakura`) and different browsers (`g:netrw_browsex_viewer` set to `'uzbl-browser'`/`'firefox'`/`'google-chrome'`.

Comment: In Debian, I cannot reproduce in `vim-runtime` 7.4.826-1 (Sid/unstable and Stretch/testing), but I can in 7.4.488-7 (Jessie/stable). https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/vim

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @Carpetsmoker points out in his comment, `g:netrw_gx` determines what will be considered part of a URI.

By default it is set to `"<cfile>"`. From the docs (`:help <cfile>`):

`<cfile>    is replaced with the path name under the cursor`

It escapes me, **why** parameter parts (i.e. `?`) of a URL are being disregarded as parts of a "path name", but I finally chose to set the following, as my solution:

```
" Use whole "words" when opening URLs.
" This avoids cutting off parameters (after '?') and anchors (after '#'). 
" See http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2801/1631
let g:netrw_gx="<cWORD>"
```

Now this includes whatever `W` would select. (Try `viW` on a string in VIM.)

From the docs:
`<cWORD>    is replaced with the WORD under the cursor`

---

Hint: Using `gx` in **visual mode**, it will open the visually selected string (regardless of the above configuration).

Comment: Another strange behaviour: When the URI ends in a `/`, it's first downloaded (with `curl`) and then opened. Removing the trailing `/`, the URI is directly opened in the browser.

Comment: "path name" is defined by the `'isfname'` option, which doesn't include `?` as a valid file name character by default.  Changing this option requires care because it can't be set local to the buffer.  Unless NetRW is changing this option, then that explains why the OPs URLs don't work with `gx`.  Maybe there's a difference in NetRW versions being used, which would explain the different behavior Carpetsmoker sees.

Answer (score 2):

On my Mac, I had to use the following in my `.vimrc`

```
nmap gx viW"ay:!open <C-R>a &<CR>
```

Explanation:

- `viW"ay` copies to the `a` register
- `<C-R>a` pastes from it
- `!open` calls MacOS default open util.

Comment: This is awesome and nearly too simple to not be angry about myself to have lived w/o that for so long :-)
That way I can add custom openers e.g. for path only github repos in my plugins.lua file `nmap gh viW"ay:!firefox https://github.com/<C-R>a &<CR>`